# Setting up row components for element-ui table

Tags: vue.js, components, element-ui

just started using Vue and Element UI libraray but got stuck with their table component: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

I'd like to have a component for each table row to handle all logic related to that row (actions, click, etc.) in this component but checking their documentation looks like the components are column-based. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to be able to perform a series of operations on the current row in the last column (Operations)? Such as editing and delete function

Comment: Yes, or handling a click on a table row element.

I'm kind of new to Vue so correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding was that I put everything in a component that belongs together and can be handled independently. So in my example the list takes care of loading the elements from the backend, handles endless scrolling, etc. and the row component everything related to one entry of the table.

Comment: After setting attribute `data` of `el-table` with an object array, you have access to the following data: `row`, `column`, `$index` and store (state management of Table) by `Scoped slot`.

Answer (score 3):

Let me show you how to use the basic `el-table`, such as processing the data of a row

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: [{
        date: '2016-05-03',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
      }, {
        date: '2016-05-02',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
      }, {
        date: '2016-05-04',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
      }, {
        date: '2016-05-01',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleEdit(index, row) {
      console.log(index, row);
    },
    handleDelete(index, row) {
      // Here you can access the row data (objects in the object array) to be deleted
      console.log(index, row);
      this.$confirm('This will permanently delete the record. Continue?', 'Warning', {
        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        type: 'warning'
      }).then(() => {
        this.tableData.splice(index, 1);
        this.$message({
          type: 'success',
          message: 'Delete completed'
        });
      }).catch(() => {
        this.$message({
          type: 'info',
          message: 'Delete canceled'
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      label="Date"
      width="180">
      <template slot-scope="scope">
        <i class="el-icon-time"></i>
        <span style="margin-left: 10px">{{ scope.row.date }}</span>
      </template>
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column label="Name" width="180">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <el-tag size="medium">{{ scope.row.name }}</el-tag>
      </template>
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column label="Operations">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <el-button
          size="mini"
          @click="handleEdit(scope.$index, scope.row)">Edit</el-button>
        <el-button
          size="mini"
          type="danger"
          @click="handleDelete(scope.$index, scope.row)">Delete</el-button>
      </template>
  </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Sugars'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794867/8058709) answer you can toggle an input to allow edits throughout the columns on each row. I've made a simple demo based on his answer.

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: [{
        date: '2016-05-03',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        editable: false
      }, {
        date: '2016-05-02',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        editable: false
      }, {
        date: '2016-05-04',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        editable: false
      }, {
        date: '2016-05-01',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        editable: false
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleEdit(index, row) {
      console.log(index, row);
      row.editable = !row.editable;
    },
    handleDelete(index, row) {
      // Here you can access the row data (objects in the object array) to be deleted
      console.log(index, row);
      this.$confirm('This will permanently delete the record. Continue?', 'Warning', {
        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        type: 'warning'
      }).then(() => {
        this.tableData.splice(index, 1);
        this.$message({
          type: 'success',
          message: 'Delete completed'
        });
      }).catch(() => {
        this.$message({
          type: 'info',
          message: 'Delete canceled'
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      label="Date"
      width="180">
      <template slot-scope="scope">
        <i class="el-icon-time"></i>
        <span style="margin-left: 10px" v-if="!scope.row.editable">{{ scope.row.date }}</span>
        <el-date-picker v-model="scope.row.date" v-if="scope.row.editable"></el-date-picker>
      </template>
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column label="Name" width="180">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <el-tag size="medium" v-if="!scope.row.editable">{{ scope.row.name }}</el-tag>
        <el-input v-model="scope.row.name" v-if="scope.row.editable"></el-input>
      </template>
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column label="Operations">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <el-button
          size="mini"
          @click="handleEdit(scope.$index, scope.row)">Edit</el-button>
        <el-button
          size="mini"
          type="danger"
          @click="handleDelete(scope.$index, scope.row)">Delete</el-button>
      </template>
  </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
  </template>
</div>
```